# C# WPF Need quickly shrink images that contain text

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I need to shrink multiple images that contain text. Because of the text they need to be shrunk in such a way as to retain the sharp edges of the text and not smoothed. My first attempt was the following:

```
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(upgradeCard, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
upgradeCard.Height(resizedHeight);
upgradeCard.Width(resizedWidth);
```

The result was too blurry, the text was hard to read. It was, however, really really fast. I then tried this:

```
public static class ImageResizer
{
    public static Image Resize(Image image, Size size)
    {
        if (image == null || size.IsEmpty)
            return null;

        var resizedImage = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height, image.PixelFormat);
        resizedImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
        {
            var location = new Point(0, 0);
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
            graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(location, size),
                               new Rectangle(location, image.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        return resizedImage;
    }
}
```

This worked really well, almost as good as Photoshop Bicubic Sharper. Unfortunately it was also very slow. Way too slow for what I need.

Is there any other way of doing this that produces the results of the second method but does so fairly quickly?

Comment: You can see this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/) that compares several image processing libraries in terms of their performance and resized image quality. But result is not very suprising - they are either fast or produces high quality images but not both at once.

Answer (score 0):

Without examples of your images it's hard to give reliable advice.

For example, how much contrast is in your images already? By what factor are you reducing them?

You could try nearest neighbour scaling, which can be very fast, and then try blurring the output slightly with a Gaussian filter, or similar. If that's too aliased, you could also try linear scaling with a soft blur.